# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Users/ANA/laravel/app/resources/views/survey/detail.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I trying to create a survey website, so I found some example that I want to test it and change it as I want, but the problem is when I choose the question type to be "Radio" OR "Checkbox" I get this error message:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Users/ANA/laravel/app/resources/views/survey/detail.blade.php)
```

I know now there is something wrong passing to foreach, but I don't know what!.
It's my first time to use Laravel, that why I'm struggling to know what's going on.

And this is the highlighted code after the error message:

```
  </div>
              </div>
              <?php elseif($question->question_type === 'radio'): ?>
                <?php $__currentLoopData = $question->option_name; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $key=>$value): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="<?php echo e($key); ?>" />
                    <label for="<?php echo e($key); ?>"><?php echo e($value); ?></label>
                  </p>
                <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
              <?php elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox'): ?>
                <?php $__currentLoopData = $question->option_name; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $key=>$value): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo e($key); ?>" />
                  <label for="<?php echo e($key); ?>"><?php echo e($value); ?></label>
                </p>
                <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

This is the code detail.blade.php:

```html
    @extends('master')
@section('title', 'Survey')

@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title"> {{ $survey->title }}</span>
    <p>
      {{ $survey->description }}
    </p>
    <br/>
    <a href='view/{{$survey->id}}'>Take Survey</a> | <a href="{{$survey->id}}/edit">Edit Survey</a> | <a href="/survey/answers/{{$survey->id}}">View Answers</a> <a href="#doDelete" style="float:right;" class="modal-trigger red-text">Delete Survey</a>
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <!-- TODO Fix the Delete aspect -->
    <div id="doDelete" class="modal bottom-sheet">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <h4>Are you sure?</h4>
            <p>Do you wish to delete this survey called "{{ $survey->title }}"?</p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="/survey/{{ $survey->id }}/delete" class=" modal-action waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text">Yep yep!</a>
              <a class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light green white-text btn">No, stop!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider" style="margin:20px 0px;"></div>
    <p class="flow-text center-align">Questions</p>
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
        @forelse ($survey->questions as $question)
        <li style="box-shadow:none;">
          <div class="collapsible-header">{{ $question->title }} <a href="/question/{{ $question->id }}/edit" style="float:right;">Edit</a></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div style="margin:5px; padding:10px;">
                {!! Form::open() !!}
                  @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                    {{ Form::text('title')}}
                  @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                      <label for="textarea1">Provide answer</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')
                    @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" />
                        <label for="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                      </p>
                    @endforeach
                  @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                    @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $key }}" />
                      <label for="{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                    </p>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        @empty
          <span style="padding:10px;">Nothing to show. Add questions below.</span>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
    <h2 class="flow-text">Add Question</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ $survey->id }}/questions" id="boolean">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <select class="browser-default" name="question_type" id="question_type">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>
            <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
            <option value="radio">Radio Buttons</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="title" id="title" type="text">
          <label for="title">Question</label>
        </div>
        <!-- this part will be chewed by script in init.js -->
        <span class="form-g"></span>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Could you please help me, I'm struggling here, I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Obviously `$__currentLoopData` is not an array. Or one of your other `foreach` inputs, this is so messy I can't really be bothered to pick it apart.  For [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2d7cc432379d2f477b87daa3be1d2f6a194e885)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, everything was correct except this line in the master.blade.php:

```
{!! MaterializeCSS::include_css() !!}
```

AND

```
{!! MaterializeCSS::include_js() !!}
```

I change them to be like the other and the code now working ^^. Just change them to look like this one :

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```